# Regex to capture Letters & Spaces

Tags: regex, c++11

I have a spec that says a particular field will be alpha-text, right-padded with spaces to be 10 characters long, and I want to capture the alpha-part of the match.

This expression captures the entire section:

```
"([[:alpha:][:s:]]{10})"
```

However, I only want to capture the alpha-part, and still match (but not capture) on the remaining white-space.   So if the alpha is 3-characters long, the next match needs to 7 white-spaces.

How can I do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, regex does not know how to count. Since the total character count is only ten, you can get away with [an ugly regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/wU4xK9/1), but I would recommend against it in all but extreme cases.

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern will match a string, starting with (optional) [A-Za-z] characters, ending with upto 10 spaces, for a total string length of 10.

```
"^([A-Za-z]+)?\\ {0,10}"
```

Then, I added a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure the pattern only matches when the string length is 10.

```
"^(?=.{10}$)([A-Za-z]+)?\\ {0,10}$"
```

Edit: Try this using the [:alpha:] and [:space:]

```
"^(?=.{10}$)([:alpha:]+)?[:space:]{0,10}$"
```

Comment: The requirement is the other way around. [a-zA-Z] characters on the left

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using [ECMAScript](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/), which is a bit of a different format.  But this solution hints at a possible way forward.

Comment: @iismathwizard what difference does it make? I would think A-Z should come before a-z aesthetically.

Comment: @Zachafer that's not what im talking about... The spaces are on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet is to use 2 regular expressions. Regex doesn't really have support for what you're trying to do.

The first regular expression would get all strings length 10 right padded by spaces

```
([a-zA-Z\s]{10})
```

After that, just capture the word part. We know each string is only 10 characters at this point.

```
(\w+)\s*
```